# bash: terraform: command not found, export $PATH unresolved

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terraform, devops

All my efforts to run terraform(exe) from command line in Ubuntu are unsuccessful

```
~/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2$ terraform init ./platforms/metal
terraform: command not found
```

I changed ~/.profile file

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2:$PATH"
```

and latter sym link

```
/usr/bin# ls -l terraform
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 dec  6 16:29 terraform -> /home/milenko/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2
```

I don't understand what is wrong.If I try what Asere suggested

```
ln -s /home/milenko/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2/terraform /usr/bin/terraform
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/terraform/terraform': File exists
```

Comment: In your example, `/home/milenko/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2` seems to be a folder ... Are you sure you shouldn't write something like `ln -s /home/milenko/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2/terraform /usr/bin/terraform` instead ?

Comment: @Aserre Take a look at my edit please!

Comment: @MikiBelavista You have to remove your old, invalid link first. `rm /usr/bin/terraform`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the fix, and then the explanation:

```
ln -snf /home/milenko/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2/terraform /usr/bin/terraform
# or equivalently:
#rm /usr/bin/terraform
#ln -s /home/milenko/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2/terraform /usr/bin/terraform
```

Currently you have `/usr/bin/terraform` pointing to `/home/milenko/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2`.

Which is not correct, because the `terraform` binary is in `/home/milenko/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2/terraform`.

You need to make `/usr/bin/terraform` point to `/home/milenko/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2/terraform`.

Let's understand what's happening here:

> ```
> ln -s /home/milenko/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2/terraform /usr/bin/terraform
> ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/terraform/terraform': File exists
> ```

Why does the command fail?
Since `/usr/bin/terraform` exists,
and it points to `/home/milenko/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2`,
the above comment will not try to replace `/usr/bin/terraform`,
but try to create `/usr/bin/terraform/terraform`.
And since `/usr/bin/terraform` points to `/home/milenko/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2`, `/usr/bin/terraform/terraform` already exists, it's actually the same thing as `/home/milenko/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2/terraform`.
And so the file exists, and the command fails.

One solution is to remove the incorrect symlink `/usr/bin/terraform` and then re-run `ln -s /home/milenko/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2/terraform /usr/bin/terraform`.

Another solution is to add the `-f` and `-n` flags to `ln`,
to force replace the symlink:

```
ln -snf /home/milenko/tectonic_1.7.9-tectonic.2/terraform /usr/bin/terraform
```

Answer (score 3):

### Jan, 2022 Update:

You better install **Terraform** again following [The Official Terraform Website](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/install-cli). But for example, to install **Terraform** for **Ubuntu** and **Debian**, we need to run 4 commands as shown below which is troublesome. Moreover each time we open a terminal, we need to run the 4 commands below which is more troublesome:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y gnupg software-properties-common curl
```

```
curl -fsSL https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main"
```

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install terraform
```

So I concatenate them above with **"&&"** as shown below so that we can run them above at once and it works fine. Just copy, paste and run the command below for **Ubuntu** and **Debian**:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y gnupg software-properties-common curl &&
curl -fsSL https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | sudo apt-key add - &&
sudo apt-add-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" &&
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install terraform
```

I searched a lot for the error **"bash: terraform: command not found"** but there aren't any easy solutions.